# How to update this to use cursor-based pagination instead?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I the following code in my app to get a list of all orders in shopify. The API calls 2019-07  have been deprecated and now am trying to update the following code  to use the latest cursor-based pagination
instead.

I use this Shopify API Client
https://github.com/nyalex/shopify-generating-api-token-guide

```
<?php
require_once("inc/functions.php");

$requests = $_GET;
//$hmac           = $_GET['hmac'];
$serializeArray = serialize($requests);
$requests       = array_diff_key($requests, array('hmac' => ''));
ksort($requests);
$token    = "xxxxxxxxx";
$shop     = "xxxxxxxxxx";   
$storeURL = "https://" . $shop . ".myshopify.com";
$allOrder = array();
$i        = 1;
do {
    $array  = array('limit' => '250', 'status' => 'any', 'page' => $i);
    $orders = shopify_call($token, $shop, '/admin/api/2019-07/orders.json', $array, 'GET');
    $orders = json_decode($orders['response'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $i++;
    foreach ($orders['orders'] as $order) {
        $allOrder[] = $order;
    }
} while (count($orders['orders']) != 0);

//print_r($orders);
?>
```

Thank You

Comment: The only issue is that if you want to get a specific page, you will need to do the math of the total count vs page item count and cycle through to that exact page

Answer (score 0):

**Implement**

If you want to implement cursor-based pagination here are a couple of links that will help you:

[Make paginated requests to the REST Admin API](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/make-paginated-requests-to-rest-admin-api) - fundamentals and a brief explanation

[How to Use Relative Pagination In Your Application](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/relative-pagination) - more comprehensive guide on how to use relative-based pagination. Includes both available types `since_id` parameters and `Link` header.

**Use existing solution**

If you just want to make your code work, you can use one of the API libraries. Some of them you can find on this page: [Shopify Admin API libraries](https://shopify.dev/tools/libraries/admin-api). There are 3 of them, seems like at least 2 do support cursor-based pagination:

- [php-shopify](https://github.com/phpclassic/php-shopify)
- [https://github.com/osiset/Basic-Shopify-API](http://Basic-Shopify-API)
- I also know [this one](https://github.com/slince/shopify-api-php) which is not listed there but works with cursor-based pagination as well
- Give a try to my [Shopify RESTful API client for PHP](https://github.com/vladimircatrici/shopify-api) which is in development but also supports new pagination, see [Collections example](https://github.com/vladimircatrici/shopify-api#collection). It would be good to get some feedback on this.